# RecyclerView now showing above a RelativeLayout(TextView and ImageView)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to position a RecyclerView above a LinearLayout( that consists of a bunch of TextViews and an ImageView), but no matter how much I try, I can only get either the RecyclerView OR the LinearLayout to show up. Not Both.

What I am trying to do is simulate a Tweet screen as seen in the Twitter app. The nested RelativeLayout is the tweet, and the RecyclerView is the list of tweets replied to by the user.

BONUS - If someone can also help me figure out how to 'hide' the recyclerView above the screen to show only if the user scrolls up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/in_reply_to"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_image"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/real_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_image"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/user_image"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/real_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_image"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/user_image"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tweet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/user_image"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why is the whole layout wrapped in `ScrollView`?

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to automatically have the app scroll to the Tweet rather than the RecyclerView